# Duplicate Request Parameters being recorded in the snippet

Tags: spring-restdocs

As the title suggests I have a Controller endpoint I'm trying to document. The endpoint can take 2 parameters both are optional. When it goes to generate the code the parameter is duplicated.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/bitbucket/project")
    public Project findProject(@RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) String key,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name)
    {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(key))
            {
                    try
                    {
                            Project project = projectService.findProjectByKey(key);
                            if (project == null)
                            {
                                    throw new NotFoundException("Project not found");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    return project;
                            }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            throw new ServerException(e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
            else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(name))
            {
                    try
                    {
                            Project project = projectService.findProjectByName(name);
                            if (project == null)
                            {
                                    throw new NotFoundException("Project not found");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    return project;
                            }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            throw new ServerException(e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    throw new BadRequestException("Project not found");
            }
    }
```

**Documentation**

```
@Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation(
            "target/generated-snippets");

    private RestDocumentationResultHandler document;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
            this.document = document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                    preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));

            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                    .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                    .alwaysDo(this.document).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findProjectKey() throws Exception
    {
            String projectKey = "KEY";
            when(projectService.findProjectByKey(anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(createProject(projectKey, null, false));

            getMockMvc().perform(get("/bitbucket/project").param("key", projectKey))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

And here is the generated snippet for the http-request.adoc

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
GET /bitbucket/project?key=KEY&key=KEY HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

----
```

Running Spring Boot 1.4.0 and Rest Docs 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/286) in 1.1.1. Upgrading to 1.1.2 will fix the problem.

Comment: Still an issue after updating to 1.1.2

Comment: Are you sure you're using 1.1.2 of spring-restdocs-core? As you are using Spring Boot you should override `spring-restdocs.version` in your pom.xml or build.gradle.

Comment: I'll test it out and get back to you. I only changed the version at the dependency level of my pom.xml

Comment: yep that worked. Helps when you put the version in the correct spot. Thanks,